# Facebook Page IFrame Tab, show user's full name

Tags: facebook, iframe, tabs

I want to show a "Hello, Jane Doe" message on my tab, when a person named Jane Doe visits it. I have found number of ways to do it, but with the new facebook iFrame and PHP SDK non of them seem to work. Is it possible to do this without asking for additional permissions from the user ? Can some one help me with the code, please?

The last thing i tried was this:

```
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
$req = $facebook->api('/me/?access_token='.$access_token);
echo $req['name'];
```

But the error i got was:

> Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be
>   used to query information about the current user.

Answer (score 0):

The users identifiable information such as their name is not available from a Facebook iframe page tab without making users authenticate with your application. The information that is availble are things like their language, country, and whether they like your page, as documented [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) and are sent over in the signed_request HTTP post parameter.

Answer (score 0):

it is still possible, but only with the "static fbml" app that does not even allow you use your own 16x16 icon for the tab.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/userlink/

static fbml also seems to render even deprecated and deleted fbml-tags, that is why it´s still working (i just tried). without that, it is not possible without user authentication anymore.